# How to handle changes made to parameters outside of CF stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Let's say I created a stack with the following parameters/resources:

```
Parameters:
  RDSAllocatedStorage:
    Type: Number
    Default: 20
    Description: Name of the S3 bucket to deploy for storing cloudtrail logs
Resources:
  RdsPrimary:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: 
        Ref: RDSAllocatedStorage
      DBName: Database123
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
```

Then in AWS console in RDS Properties I manually change the property RDSAllocatedStorage from 20 to 30. This, however, will not change the parameter RDSAllocatedStorage in Outputs of the stack in CF, so now CF doesn't reflect what's deployed.

Now if I modify the CF change RDSAllocatedStorage to 30 in the template, create a changeset, CF will think there is a change to be made because RDSAllocatedStorage in the stack is 20, incoming change is 30, but in reality there should be no need for a change because the setting on RDS is already set to 30.

Is there a way to bring CF parameter in line with what's actually in resources?

Comment: I've been testing on a large stack and was getting some issues, turned out unrelated - just tested on a simple stack with two resources and it worked great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is called [drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html) and its a very bad practice to make any changes to your resources outside of CFN. But if you have drift, there are few things you can do as described in AWS docs:

- [Remediate drift via resource import with AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/remediate-drift-via-resource-import-with-aws-cloudformation/)
- [Resolve drift with an import operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-resolve-drift.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'll give it a go.